# C++ compiler error, erasing letter from word

Tags: c++, string, function, compiler-errors

Compiler shows this error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' and 'void')
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void remove(string x, string y)
{
   while (x.find_first_of(y) != -1)
   {
      x.erase(x.find_first_of(y), 1);
   }
}

int main()
{
   string a, b;
   cout << "Enter word: ";
   cin >> a;
   cout << "Sign: ";
   cin >> b;
   cout << "Result: " << remove(a, b) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function doesn't return anything (that is what is meant by void) . So you can't output anything

Write

```
string remove(string x,string y){
..............
return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`remove()` function is void, which returns nothing. However, `cout` doesn't overload the operator `<<` for void datatype.